# Android screen sizes - containing folders

Tags: android, resize, dpi, screen-size, android-screen-support

I'm trying to get my app Android app to support multiple screen sizes.
I want it to only support phones(From 3 inches to 5.7), not Tablets.

I have two test phones - Samsung Galaxy S2 and Nexus 4.

I'm trying to 'play' with the different folders(LDPI,MDPI,HDPI and XHDPI) but I can't get a consistent result.

I don't want to use different layout for each screen size, only to resize the resources.
Which folders should I user? If I use the basic four DPI folders(resized resources in each folder) it doesn't work well, and both phones uses the same resource folder.

I've tried playing with screen sizes and DPI folders -

```
drawable-large-ldpi
drawable-large-mdpi
drawable-large-hdpi
drawable-large-xhdpi
```

But still no luck.

Any tips on this one? I've read the [Supporting Multiple Screens page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that in youar Manifest file saying which screen sizes your appshould support. something like this

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Comment: Yeah I know, I'll do that to exclude largeScreens(Tablets), but it still doesn't solve my problems with the phone screen sizes.

Comment: The supports-screens tag is only for the Google Play. It simply doesn't let you download the app on non-supported devices.

Answer (score 0):

S2 falls under normal-hdpi while Nexus 4 falls under normal-xhdpi. Provide assets in the normal hdpi and xhdpi folders.

Comment: I did that, but for some reason the Nexus 4 uses to assets from the normal-hdpi folder.